# Why android app crash

Tags: java, android, json

Why android app crash on line `JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) object;` ?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    private static final String TAG = "myLogs";
            String s = "{\"paramsArray\": [\"first\", 100],"
                + "\"paramsObj\": {\"one\": \"two\", \"three\": \"four\"},"
                + "\"paramsStr\": \"some string\"}";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.parse_text_test);

        TextView textViewTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try {
            Object object = parser.parse(s);
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) object; // crash
            //textViewTest.setText(jsonObject.toString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you are using

```
org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser
```

which creates

```
org.json.simple.JSONObject
```

instances, but trying to assign them to

```
org.json.JSONObject
```

type variables.

Fix your dependencies and `import` statements.

Comment: so in your opinion is a ClassCastException?

Comment: @blackbelt I think so. AFAIK the Android SDK provides the `org.json.JSONObject` class, but not the `org.json.simple` classes which OP seems to be using.